# Issue with filtering by age when Date of Birth is stored in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have done quite a bit of research and haven't found anything of relevance. The issue is that my Users table has a DOB column. And my User model has an age method that calculates the users age. I am able to display the users age as follows: `current_user.age` and it works just fine. But I can't use age in a query as it is not an attribute in the User model. How do other website, for example dating websites provide a filter by age option? I can't imagine them having an age column in the database as it would be painful to keep updating it. In short, how can I filter results based on a range of ages provided by a User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to find users between and including ages 18 and 20 as of today, and you're storing the DOB in a field called `dob`.

A person exactly 18 years old today would have been born on Apr 6, 1995. And one who's turning 21 tomorrow would be born on Apr 7, 1993.

So you want users with DOB between and including Apr 5, 1993 and Apr 6, 1995.

```
18.years.ago.to_date
=> Thu, 06 Apr 1995
(20.years.ago + 1.day).to_date
=> Mon, 07 Apr 1993
```

You can use this now

```
User.where("dob >= ? AND dob <= ?", 20.years.ago + 1.day, 18.years.ago)
```

Comment: Okay. But how do I pass in params? Because a User will have a text input form to insert ages from XX to XX

Comment: @pratski, what format are you sending the data from the client side form to the server?

Comment: Well, its a blueprint. This is what I have so far:   `<form>
  <div class="filtertext">
  Ages from: <input type="text" class="gteq">
  to <input type="text" class="gteq">
  </div>
  <div style ="margin-top:10px;"> <%= link_to "Filter",'#', class: "searchprofilebutton" %> </div>
  </form>`

Comment: @pratski, you'll need to add a `name` field to the form inputs (I think you already know that). In your controller just use `params[:min_age].to_i` and `params[:max_age].to_i` instead of `18` and `20` in the last line of code in my answer.

Comment: You may want to make your search more precise and catch all users who have been born that year, so in case of ages 18 to 20, do this:
```User.where("dob >= ? AND dob <= ?", 20.years.ago.to_date.beginning_of_year, 18.years.ago.to_date.end_of_year)```

Comment: pratski, when did you place the code at? I have been using "User.where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", Date.today - youngest_age, Date.today - oldest_age)" but I get a error when I do it. Is it inside the search or users controller? I have been struggling with this as well. Trying to add the code and then have a form for it on my advanced search form.